# How to set random locations to poly objects in Maya with Python?

Tags: python, maya

So here is my code:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
import random

x = random.random() * 10
y = random.random() * 10
z = random.random() * 10

for i in range(5):
    mycube = mc.polyCube(h=3, w=3, d=3, n="Object#")
    mc.move(x, y, z, mycube)
```

Things should be clear what I am trying to do. I'm creating 5 `polyCube`'s and setting them random location in 3 dimensional world. My version of Maya is 2009 if it helps.

Comment: Move the `x = ...` lines into the `for` loop.

Comment: `random.random` is not generating values in negative. And `random.randint` is not looking sufficient! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `x`, `y` and `z` lines inside the for loop. Thanks [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender) for pointing it out.

Another unusual thing you might notice when running this updated code is that cubes that are created are on a certain section on the viewport. That is because `random.random` is not creating values in negatives, so value is not going in negative in either of the axis `x`, `y` and `z`.

[image: When we use random.random]

To overcome this problem you can replace the codes in x y and z definition lines:

```
x = random.uniform(-10.0, 10.0)
y = random.uniform(-10.0, 10.0)
z = random.uniform(-10.0, 10.0)
```

[image: When we use random.uniform]

Now it works as expected.